# SQL to retrieve all linked records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a product table (tProduct) and a product links table (tProductLink) to allow establishing links between products. Given a ProductID and ProductLinkID, I need to get all of the tProduct.ID records that are related.

In the example table (tProductLink) below, all of the ID's would be returned. Note that it's not possible to create a recursive link; that is given the first row in the table below there cannot be a row where ProductID is 31563 and ProductID is 28818.

So say I search for all products related to the link in row 4, ProductID 137902 and LinkProductID 410901. Give that link, it should return all six rows.

Here is an example of the data.

[image: Table Examples.]

I have tried various techniques such as a recursive CTE and calling a table function using "cross apply" but I have got nowhere.

This is one of the last solutions I tried, which ended up not returning all products as noted in the comments.

```
declare @ProductID int, @ProductLinkID int
select @ProductID = 137902
select @ProductLinkID = 410901

;with p1 as
(
     select ProductID, ProductLinkID
     from tProductLink
     where ProductID = @ProductID and ProductLinkID = @ProductLinkID
     union all
     select tProductLink.ProductID, tProductLink.ProductLinkID
     from tProductLink
     join p1 on p1.ProductLinkID = tProductLink.ProductID
     where not (tProductLink.ProductID = @ProductID and tProductLink.ProductLinkID = @ProductLinkID)
)
select distinct ProductID from p1
union
select ProductLinkID from p1
```

Comment: Why didn't recursive CTE work? Show us what have you tried and how it failed.

Comment: Is the table in your question your actual source data (*Not* the result of an intermediate script) or your desired result?  Whichever one is in your question, could you please add the other one?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get back - Could you explain / show what you're trying to return?

Comment: Definitely a recursive CTE solution is correct here.

Comment: @JiriTousek I was joining recursively wrong. I posted an answer that I think works, though I need to test it more.

Comment: @john-bustos I wasn't clear on that. I updated my question and posted a potential solution as an answer. I want to get all the ProductID and ProductLinkID values. Basically I want to identity all rows in tProduct that are in tProductLink related to a given link.

Comment: @iamdave I posted the actual tables, but I left columns not relative to this problem.

Comment: In your example all products are linked. It shouldn't matter, with which ID (or, now that you've altered the request, with which link record) to start with. Correct?

Comment: And it doesn't make a difference whether you link 410901->28520 or 28520->410901, Right? In both cases you link the two products. Yes?

Comment: BTW: Next time please don't post an image, but paste your data as text, so we can copy and paste to work with it.

Comment: @thorsten-kettner In the example, yes, all products are linked. Though in the actual database there are more than 400,000 products and 10,000 product links.

Comment: If you agree with my statements, then you can check the queries by starting at another point. Your query doesn't show all IDs when you start with (410901,28818) for instance. It also doesn't when you switch (410901,28520) and (410901,28818) to (28520,410901) and (28818,410901).

Comment: @thorsten-kettner I see, you're correct that my solution does not include all the rows I need. Your solution indeed answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with one ID. This can be in multiple rows `ProductLinkId` or `ProductId` in the second table. You look up the corresponding IDs thus found again in the second table.

This asks for a recursive query, where you always collect all corresponding IDs. Unfortunately SQL Server does not support `DISTINCT` in recursive queries, so the same IDs get looked up multiple times. SQL Server also doesn't prevent from cycles (but fails instead), so we must prevent them ourselves by remembering which IDs we already found. This would ideally be done with an array or set that we fill, but SQL Server doesn't support such, so we must build a string instead.

The complete query:

```
with cte(id, seen) as
(
  select 28520 as id, cast('/28520/' as varchar(max)) as seen from t1
  union all
  select case when cte.id = t2.productid then t2.linkproductid 
                                         else t2.productid end as id,
    cte.seen + cast(case when cte.id = t2.productid 
                      then t2.linkproductid 
                      else t2.productid end as varchar(max)) + '/'
  from cte
  join t2 on cte.id in (t2.productid, t2.linkproductid) 
    and charindex('/' + cast(case when cte.id = t2.productid
                               then t2.linkproductid
                               else t2.productid end as varchar(max))+ '/', cte.seen) = 0
)
select distinct id from cte
option (maxrecursion 1000);
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WJJ78304